# Multiplication of two results vue js version 3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I’m using vue3, I’m trying to multiply two results but I get either NaN or bad results.I get the decimal 00 instead of 10. I have been on the vuejs forum for 3 days, but we could not fix the problem. I have done 3 different ways but none of them work.At first I thought the problem was that I was fetching from localstorage, but I tried putting direct numbers in but it also doesn’t work. I put the images of the screenshots from the console.log for each way I did and I put a screenshot of what is displayed in the app. Thank you in advance for the help.

```
<template>
    <div>
         <!--test 1 -->
        <p> {{ total }} </p>
        <!-- test 2 -->
        <p> {{ total2 }}
        <!--test3-->
        <p> {{ total3 }}
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
    name:"VehiculeSearchResa",
    data(){
        return{
           //test1
           // total 1
           priceLoc: localStorage.getItem('price'), //26,52
           numberDays : localStorage.getItem('numberDays'), //14
           //test2
            // total 2
            days: 14,
            price: '26,52',
        }
    },
    computed:{
       //test1
       total1(){
            let priceTotal = this.numberDays * parseFloat(this.priceLoc).toFixed(2)
            return 
      }
       //test2
      total2(){
           let totalprice =  this.days * parseFloat(this.price).toFixed(2)
           console.log(totalprice)
           return totalprice
           }
           //test3
            total3(){
                 let day= 14
                 let priceTest= '26,52'
                 let total3 = day* parseFloat(priceTest).toFixed(2)
                 console.log(total3)
                 return total3
           }
    }
    
}
</script>
```

[image app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LHBcL.jpg)

[image console log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dltdi.jpg)

Comment: `parseFloat("26,52")` returns 26. You need to use `.` for decimal. Also, if `localStorage.getItem('price')` returns `null`, `parseFloat(null)` returns `NaN`

Comment: thank you very much @adiga , I put the 'point'  and it works. so when we multiply we must put a 'point '  instead of 'comma' ?

Comment: Javascript uses `.` for decimal not `,`.